# Upload com java script

Tags: php, javascript, html, upload

Tenho o seguinte código para upload de imagem porém só funciona se o js estiver na mesma página do formulário e não funciona vindo o js de arquivo externo, gostaria de usar externo por que uso outras funções, alguém poderia me explicar o por que não funciona o js externo ou dar alguma dica? agradecido!

HTML

```
<head>

<title>Image Upload Form</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/teste.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post" id="fileinfo" name="fileinfo" ">
<label>Select a file:</label><br>
<input type="file" name="file" required onchange='return submitForm();'/>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

js externo

```
function submitForm() {
        console.log("submit event");
        var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("fileinfo"));
        fd.append("label", "WEBUPLOAD");
        $.ajax({
          url: "../teste.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: fd,
          processData: false,  
          contentType: false   
        }).done(function( data ) {
            console.log("PHP Output:");
            console.log( data );
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Php

```
if ($_POST["label"]) {
$label = $_POST["label"];
}
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {
    $filename = $label.$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $filename)) {
        echo $filename . " already exists. ";
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
        "upload/" . $filename);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $filename;
    }
}
} else {
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele funciona, tanto externo quanto embutido no código. Você só precisar definir o caminho correto. Acredito que você tenha mudado o caminho do código e por isso não funciona. Se o teste.php estiver na raiz, junto com HTML, mude:

```
url: "../teste.php"
```

para:

```
url: "teste.php",
```

Ou então use o caminho absoluto que não tem erro.

Comment: era isso! obrigado!

Answer (score -2):

Ele funciona, tanto externo quanto embutido no código. Você só precisar definir o caminho correto. Acredito que você tenha mudado o caminho do código e por isso não funciona. Se o teste.php estiver na raiz, junto com HTML, mude:

url: "../teste.php"

Comment: Qual o objetivo desse texto? Você copia e cola a resposta de outro colega, não acrescentando nada a página. Se quer formular uma pergunta comece lendo [ask]. Também faça um [tour] para aprender uma poco mais do funcionamento da página.